# gmappanel move to the marker coordinate - EXTJS 4

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs, extjs4

```
 function addDoctorLocation(options) 
    {
        var gm = Ext.getCmp('mygooglemap');
        var mpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(options.lat,options.lng);
        var marker = gm.addMarker(mpoint,options.marker,false,false, options.listeners);
   // move the map to the mark and adjust the zoom level at here
    }

        tree.on('checkchange', function(node){
            var data = node.data;

            if (data.checked == true){

            lati = 5.391788482666016; 
            longi = 100.29693603515625; 

            var options = {
            lat:lati,
            lng:longi,
            marker: {title:"Hello World!"},
            listeners: {
                         click: function(e){

                                             }
                        }     
            }     
            addDoctorLocation(options);  
            }       
        })
```

### Question

how to move the map to marker there and adjust the zoom level?

Answer (score 0):

```
gm.setCenter(mpoint);
gm.setZoom(8);
```

See the methods section of google.maps.Map class here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#Map